# How to run gradle class only if the build is successfull

Tags: testing, groovy, build, gradle

I have a tests built on gradle framework. In a method with afterclass(), I call function, which cleans the environment (processes). However, I want to clean it only in case the tests are successful. Otherwise, I'd like to let it there for investigation. Here is example:

```
@AfterClass()
public void clean() {
    if (processID) {
        deleteProcess(processID)
    }
}
```

In this case, the env. is cleaned only when the tests (class) fails. If I add     @AfterClass(alwaysRun=true), the clean method is called every time.

Is there any way how to call clean method only in case the tests runs ok?

Answer (score 2):

Now assuming that you use JUnit you can achieve this by implementing a TestRule that will wrap execution of the test and conditionally do the cleanup based on the result of test run. `org.junit.rules.ExternalResource` and `org.junit.rules.TestWatcher`. The former is intended for these tasks the latter knows about test failure/success. Take a look at their sources and you can create your own support.

BTW: this isn't a Gradle specific problem as the question suggests.